# ls finds files in directory with a specific name, but find does not

Tags: find, ls

I'm trying to find all the files that are inside directories whose names start with `80s`.

`ls 80s*/*` finds the correct files, but `find . -ipath '80s*/*'` returns nothing. What is the correct `find` command for this task?

I need to use `find` since I want to move all such files to a different folder and don't want to parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: Note that in `ls 80s*/*`, it's not `ls` that finds the files, it's the shell that expands `80s*/*` into a list of file names that it then passes to `ls` (and for those of type directory, `ls` lists their contents, while for files of other type it just prints them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-ipath` matches the complete path name, including the current path `.`. So you will have to include that in your pattern:

```
find . -ipath './80s*/*'
```

The above will also output directories. To list only regular files, use:

```
find . -ipath './80s*' -type f
```

(or `! -type d` for any type of file except directories)

Comment: Also note that `-ipath` (a non-standard extension) matches file paths case insensitively so would also match on `./80S` while shell globs do not case insensitive matching by default. Also `-ipath './80s*/*'` would match on `./80s/A/B/C` while the shell glob equivalent would not generate that file (you'd need `-maxdepth 2` in `find`). `find` would also include hidden files while shell globs don't by default. GNU `find` on GNU systems at least would also exclude files whose name doesn't form valid text in the locale.

Comment: I was feeling comfortable reading your comment, @StéphaneChazelas, but the last sentence was alarm sensors going off – I have scripts that backup specific stuff using find and I have never bothered to check whether files have locale-valid text *panics*!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, see the section about **_Bytes vs characters_** at [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/321757)

Answer (score 3):

If, as you say, `80s*/*` matches the correct files, then I don't really see a reason to use `find` at all.

To move all names matching `80s*/*` to some destination directory, `destdir`, you may use

```bsh
mv -n 80s*/* destdir/
```

This moves all non-hidden names from any directory matching `80s*` into the single directory `destdir`.  The non-standard `-n` option usually means "no clobber", i.e. don't overwrite files if there are name collisions.

If using GNU `mv`, you may additionally avoid overwriting files that has the same names as other files using the `--backup` option (e.g., `--backup=numbered`), or, as above, `-n` (`--no-clobber`).

If you need to pick out only *regular* files, or if `80s*/*` expands to a far too long list of names, use a loop:

```bsh
for name in 80s*/*; do
    [ ! -f "$name" ] && continue
    mv -n "$name" destdir/
done
```

(That would also move symbolic links to regular files.  To avoid these, additionally test with `-h`/`-L` whether `"$name"` is a symbolic link or not.)

In the `zsh` shell, you could move all regular files that match your pattern using

```bsh
mv -n 80s*/*(.) destdir/
```

... where the glob qualifier `(.)` filters the results of the preceding pattern to only contain regular files (`(-.)` to also include symlinks to regular files).

---

If you really need to use `find`, then consider

```bsh
find ./80s*/ -path './80s*/*' -prune ! -name '.*' -type f \
    -exec mv -n {} destdir/ \;
```

This matches the names that you are interested in, and avoids hidden names (you said `80s*/*` matches correctly and I assume this means hidden names are not wanted). It *prunes* all matching names, meaning it avoids entering subdirectories that matches the pattern, and then, if the name corresponds to a regular file, moves the file to `destdir` using `mv -n` as before.

With GNU `mv`, you could make it slightly more efficient by using `-exec mv -n -t destdir/ {} +` in place of the original `-exec`.  This would execute `mv` with batches of found filenames instead of calling `mv` once for each name.